# Avoid using "GET" method when adding embedded Flash

Tags: html, flash, http

I need to avoid using GET HTTP method in my application for security reason.
I have the following flash in my code:

```
<OBJECT 
    style="width:130%;height:100%;position:relative;left:-180;" 
    CLASSID="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" 
    CODEBASE="https://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,40,0" 
    ID="theMovie"> 
<PARAM NAME="FlashVars" VALUE="' + sbImageList.getValue()+'"> 
<param name=Menu VALUE="TRUE">
<param name=METHOD VALUE="POST">
<PARAM NAME="src" VALUE="JPGViewer.swf"></OBJECT>
```

This embedded flash go to the server using "GET" method. Is it possible to force "POST" Method?

Comment: I wouldn't say that the html is invalid, the closing-tags are optional in HTML. However, the GET vs. POST thing is right, assuming something is more secure just because it's not immediately seen is a deep misconception of security.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that comes to my mind, that **might** work is to create a manual request with JS and then store the result in a string value and convert this to a `data://`-URL.

I've never done this nor read this anywhere though.

Comment: Before you invest your time: check if the browsers you need to support will support data-URLs at all.

Comment: And if you do this, pleas let me know if this works, I'm curious ;D